# Switch Requests to Content Specific to Requesting Domain

Tags: asp.net, apache, iis

Lets say I have several web sites on my web server, all as applications under one domain.  How could I register other domains to point to the same web server, and redirect requests to, e.g. a web site linked to the requesting domain?

I know I'll have to have a root site, and I'm guessing I may have have to do some voodoo in the request pipline on this root site, and dispatch a changed request to the relevant sub-site.

Example, I would like *acme.net* and *ajax.net* to both point to the same address as *root.net*.  When a browser requests *acme.net*, the content at *acme.root.net* or *root.net/acme*, should be served, but the user must still see *acme.net* in their address bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Apache you could do something like this:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName acme.net
   DocumentRoot C:/www/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName acme.root.net
   DocumentRoot C:/www/
</VirtualHost>
```

I hope it could be useful for you.